# How to share components with hooks between two windows?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I'm trying to share components between two windows. `index.html` has an iframe the src of which is `iframe.html`. I want `iframe.html` to render components defined in `index.html`. This works well, as long as components don't use any hooks. If hooks are used, `Invalid hook call` error occurs. Here are code for explanation. Do you have any workaround?

**index.html**

```html
<body><div id="root"></div><script src="index.js"></script></body>
```

**index.ts**

```js
import React, { FC, useState } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

const ComponentWithHook: FC = () => {
  const [value] = useState('xxxx');
  return <>{value}</>;
};

(window as any).getComponent = () => ComponentWithHook;

ReactDOM.render(<iframe src="iframe.html" />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

**iframe.html**

```html
<body><div id="root"></div><script src="iframe.js"></script></body>
```

**iframe.ts**

```js
import React, { FC } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

const Dummy: FC = () => {
  const ComponentWithHook = (top as any).getComponent();
  return <ComponentWithHook />;
};

ReactDOM.render(<Dummy />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: It feels odd to me to share component in this way. I would prefer to create another script for that component and both index.ts and iframe.ts will import and use it.

Comment: Yes, I think so in ordinary case. But it is necessary to share components in this way this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Self-solving:**
It has resolved by passing React as a prop and using it inside a component.

**index.ts**

```js
import React, { FC, useState } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

const ComponentWithHook: FC<{ React: typeof React }> = ({ React }) => {
  const [value] = React.useState('xxxx');
  return <>{value}</>;
};

(window as any).getComponent = () => ComponentWithHook;

ReactDOM.render(<iframe src="iframe.html" />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

**iframe.ts**

```js
import React, { FC } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

const Dummy: FC = () => {
  const ComponentWithHook = (top as any).getComponent();
  return <ComponentWithHook React={React} />;
};

ReactDOM.render(<Dummy />, document.getElementById('root'));
```